# Type-level restriction on "mixed" arrays, while allowing arrays of arrays with different content in the inner arrays

Tags: arrays, haskell, data-structures, types

I have the following data structure:

```
data Value =
         VString Text
       | VInteger Integer
       | VDouble Double
       | VBool Bool
       | VArray [Value]
       | VDate UTCTime
  deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)
```

The following arrays are valid according to the `Value` data type:

```
VArray [VInteger 1, VInteger 2]
VArray [VArray [VInteger 1, VInteger 2], VArray [VString "a", VString "b"]]
```

Now I want to enforce on type-level that the following arrays are prohibited (while with the above definition of `Value` they are allowed):

```
VArray [VInteger 1, VDouble 2.0]
VArray [VArray [VInteger 1, VInteger 2], VBool True]
```

In other words, I want prohibit "mixed" arrays, while allowing arrays of arrays with different content in the inner arrays. Arrays may be nested to arbitrarily deep levels.

How can I change my definition of `Value` (and possibly add other definitions) to facilitate this type-level restriction in Haskell?

I tried to my best of ability, but found myself stuck... Any help is greatly appreciated.

*NOTE:* I'm [working on a parser](https://github.com/cies/toml) for the [TOML](https://github.com/toml-lang/toml) file format, which defined arrays as mentioned above.

Some more context to the question.  This is how the `Value` is used (in a `Table`, etc.):

```
data TomlDoc = TomlDoc Table [TableNode]
data TableNode = TableNode
    Text
    (Maybe (Either Table TableArray))
    [TableNode]
  deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)

type Table = Map Text Value
type TableArray = [Table]
```

And this is how I hope to construct a document:

```
test :: TomlDoc
test =
  TomlDoc
    (M.fromList [("a", VInteger 1), ("b", VInteger 2)])
    [ TableNode "A"
        (Just . Left $ M.fromList [("aa", VInteger 1)])
        []
    , TableNode "B"
        (Just . Left $ M.fromList [("bb", VInteger 2)])
        [ TableNode "B"
            (Just . Left $ M.fromList [("bbb", VInteger 2)])
            []
        , TableNode "C"
            (Just . Right $
              [ M.fromList [("bbc", VInteger 2)]
              , M.fromList [("bbc", VArray [ VArray [VInteger 1, VInteger 2],
                                             VArray [] ])] ])
            []
        ]
    ]
```

Comment: Write `data VVArray = VAString [VString] | VSBool [VBool] | ...` and change `data Value = ... | VArray VVArray | ...`. I don't know if a better way exists (or directly split `VArray` into `Value` if you want to restrict at all levels).

Comment: It’s not clear whether you want to enforce a single nesting level for arrays, or whether each leaf array should contain values of one kind only, or both.

Comment: @JoachimBreitner Nesting is allowed to many levels, just in a particular array all types need to be equal, where the array type should allow nesting of arrays containing different types.

Comment: @josejuan Doing what you propose results in an error regarding the `VString` in the `VVArray` definition: "Data constructor VString cannot be used here (it is defined and used in the same recursive group)". I don't know how to fix that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some parts of the specification are unclear. Is an array of arrays nested to different levels valid? For example, is `VArray [VArray [VArray [VInteger 1]], VArray [VInteger 1]]` a valid value? I will cover both variants.

The basic principle is to tag Value with the type it contains:

```
data Value a where
  VString :: Text -> Value Text 
  VInteger :: Integer -> Value Integer
  VDouble :: Double -> Value Double
  VBool :: Bool -> Value Bool
  VDate :: UTCTime -> Value UTCTime
```

In the case that an array of nested arrays of different levels is valid, you simply have

```
data Array 

data Value a where 
  ....
  VArray :: [Value a] -> Value Array
```

In the other case, `Array` must know about nesting depth, so simple store the value in the array:

```
data Array a

data Value a where 
  ....
  VArray :: [Value a] -> Value (Array a)
```

Eventually you want to forget the type information. I don't know why you would want to do this, you should just carry on using the typed version. Types should help you, not hinder you. If at some point, types are *getting in your way*, you are likely doing something wrong.

But if you really want, you can erase the type:
    data Value a where 
      ....
      VUntype :: Value a -> Value ()

```
type Table = Map Text (Value ())
...

test :: TomlDoc
test =
  TomlDoc
    (M.fromList [("a", VUntype $ VInteger 1), ("b", VUntype $ VInteger 2)])
    ...
```

Be careful! This make introduce *a lot* of added complexity to code in other places:

```
func0 f (VUntype x) = VUntype (f x)
```

What is the type of this function?

```
-- Wrong
func0 :: (Value a -> Value b) -> Value () -> Value ()
func0 :: (Value a -> Value a) -> Value () -> Value ()
func0 :: (Value Integer -> Value Array) -> Value () -> Value ()
func0 :: (forall a b . Value a -> Value b) -> Value () -> Value ()
```

The last one is especially dangerous. It will compile, however, type type `forall a b . Value a -> Value b` is *uninhabited*. The only function you can write with that type is `undefined` (strictly speaking, you also have `\_ -> undefined`).

This is the correct type:
    func0 :: (forall a . Value a -> Value a) -> Value () -> Value ()

Another example:

```
-- Wrong
func1 :: (Value a -> b) -> Value () -> b
func1 :: (Value Integer -> b) -> Value () -> b

-- Right
func1 :: (forall a . Value a -> b) -> Value () -> b
func1 f (VUntype x) = f x
```

If you still need to access types at runtime, you can a) keep the types all the way through; b) change your constructor to `VUntype :: Typeable a => Value a -> Value ()`.

The last option is if you only need to use the type information for constructing valid data, and you never plan to write functions whose value uses the type. Take your original data type, use a secondary type with a phantom type parameter and only export the typed version of constructors:

```
data Value =
         VString Text
       | VInteger Integer
       | VDouble Double
       | VBool Bool
       | VArray [Value]
       | VDate UTCTime

newtype SafeValue a = SV {getSV :: Value} -- Pick a better name :)

vString :: Text -> SafeValue Text
vString = SV . VString 

....

vArray :: [SafeValue a] -> SafeValue Array
vArray = SV . VArray . map getSV
```

This has the advantage that you don't use existential types/nasty type erasure, which may make it very difficult to write well typed code. Simple write `getSV` and *properly* get rid of those nasty types.

Comment: "Is an array of arrays nested to different levels valid?" -> yes.  At least that's how I understand the TOML specification :)

Comment: Maybe a vary stupid subquestion, but before I had a `type Table = Map Text Value`, this does not work anymore because `Value` now has a param `a`. I tried to solve it with type classes, but it brings me in a cascade of language pragmas (DataKinds, RankNTypes, ImpredicativeTypes).

Comment: Small addition: your solution needs the pragma `GADTs`, which is totally cool.

Comment: You shouldn't have to use ImpredictiveTypes, and it can be a dangerous thing to enable. Try `type Table a = Map Text (Value a)`

Comment: Once I do that I have to add the `a` param all the way down, because I use `Table` in quite some places.

Comment: I added more context to the question in the original description.

Comment: @cies: You might need a wrapper for this, but try `type Table = Map Text (forall a. Value a)`.

Comment: @DavidYoung: Thanks for the help!  No matter on what type I try to define the `forall a.` wrapper, I keep running into this error: "Illegal polymorphic or qualified type: Table. Perhaps you intended to use ImpredicativeTypes"

Comment: The type `Map Text (forall a. Value a)` is bad. It will only make your life harder. In my humble opinion, ImpredictiveTypes is a misfeature and I have never seen a valid use case. I updated the answer with possible solutions to your problem.

Comment: Thank you so much for this update, I really understand what I "missed" when I got stuck on the question, namely: the fact that I only want to enforce "same types on array" when creating them. Your answer was really clear and made me understand quite a bit more about Haskell types.